# Calculate limit of $\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(\sin(x)-1)}$ as x goes to +infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried like this:

$$\frac{-1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}\leq\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(\sin(x)-1)}\leq\frac{1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}$$

for each $x$ in domain.

And now, Wolfram-Alpha says that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}=0$, therefore $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(\sin(x)-1)}=0$, but I do not know how to show that the following is true:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{x(\sin(x)-1)}=0.$$

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Your expressions +/-1/(x(1-sin(x)) are not defined at x for which sin(x)=1, and there is a sequence of such x approaching infinity. That makes a problem, for the usual definition of limit one needs the expression to be defined for large enough x.

Comment: OK, so Wolfram-Alpha is incorrect here, and the limit is indeterminate?

Comment: It may be that some kind of LHopital cancelling occurs if one does not omit the numerator sin(2x).

Comment: Hm, I do not see how I could apply LHopital here :(

Comment: gaghan: Note that the answer by M. Zhang has successfully applied LHopital to the *reciprocal* of your expression and shown it tends to zero as x tends to any value making sin(x)=1. That means your expression itself is unbounded at these points, so it has no limit.

Answer (score 3):

When $x\to\pi/2+2k\pi$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$, both $\sin(2x)$ and $x(\sin(x)-1)$ tend to zero, so we can apply L'Hopital's rule to get

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2+2k\pi}\frac{x(\sin(x)-1)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2+2k\pi}\frac{\sin(x)-1+x\cos(x)}{2\cos(2x)}=0.$$

This means $f(x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(\sin(x)-1)}$ blows up at $x=\pi/2+2k\pi$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$ and therefore the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ cannot exist.